# Run SQL Scripts and then update Entity Model in Code First set up

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have run into a situation. We are still in the development cycle and we have implemented Code First Model using EF6. Now, we have just received SQL scripts to add new tables as well as few more function scripts. Is there a way I can run those scripts with Entity Migrations? I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried. Do you want to update the SQL schema, and generate the Code First Model from the database? You can do that with the latest EF Tools

Comment: That is exactly I want to do. I have already generated the code first model from the existing database. However now, I have received new SQL scripts for new tables. I just want to run the SQL scripts and then UPDATE my code first model.

Comment: You can RECREATE the code first model based on the new schema using EF Tools or the EF Reverse POCO Template. Not sure what you mean by UPDATE? I assume you have made any manula model changes in seperate .cs files??

Comment: I was hoping there was a way I can use EF migrations to apply the changes to my Model based on what has changed in the database. So, UPDATE my model based on the UPDATES or changes in the database. Seems like there is none? :(

Comment: Migrations compares entity models, not database schemas